# Is there any problem to add a super big number after `\alignat` in ams package?

Tags: align, alignment, katex

In the [official document](http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf), `alignat` is followed by the total of "right column and left column" pairs.

Here is an examaple of `alignat` in the document.

```latex
\begin{alignat}{2}
x& = y_1-y_2+y_3-y_5+y_8-\dots
&\quad& \text{by \eqref{eq:C}}\\
& = y’\circ y^* && \text{by \eqref{eq:D}}\\
& = y(0) y’ && \text {by Axiom 1.}
\end{alignat}
```

Is there any problem to set the number following `alignat` to a big number? For example,

```latex
\begin{alignat}{999}
x& = y_1-y_2+y_3-y_5+y_8-\dots
&\quad& \text{by \eqref{eq:C}}\\
& = y’\circ y^* && \text{by \eqref{eq:D}}\\
& = y(0) y’ && \text {by Axiom 1.}
\end{alignat}
```

Doing this will reduce the effort to modify the number if I add more columns in the future.

I can't see any difference in the result rendered by KaTex.
[image]

### Update

I considered KaTex also implemented with Tex, so I provided an image about KaTex. However, what I actually care about is the implementation in Tex.

Comment: it is much more efficient to use -1

Comment: It seems that `-1` is invalid for KaTex.

Comment: katex doesn't use tex at all, so any answer here about costs and efficiency of handling a large number here would not apply to katex either.

Comment: Sorry about the straight words. I didn't argue about your comment. I just didn't know the difference between KaTex and other Tex-based implementations like LaTex.

Comment: nothing to apologise about,  it wasn't a critisism just mentioning that javascript versions like mathjax and katex are mostly off topic  here, but are OK as long as the question covers tex as well. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-do-we-feel-about-mathjax-jsmath-other-spin-offs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alignat` (like most ams aligments) builds a `\halign` template correspoding to pairs of columns alternating right and left aligment, similar to `\begin{array}{rl rl rl ...}`

So if you use `999` instead of `1` a token list 1000 times longer will be built. The loop to build this list will take longer to build and the list will take more memory.

When the code was written in ~1990 it would have taken a lot longer to run and possibly failed due to lack of token memory. These days, it's inefficient but probably not noticable in practice.

It is not over-advertised in the documentation, but you can use -1. This avoids building a list and uses a primitive feature of `\halign` that means a preamble can be marked as being repeated as often as needed.

Note all these considerations are only about the amsmath version of `alignat` which is written in TeX. In comments you indicated you were also interested in a katex version. That is implemented in JavaScript, so the implementation will be different, and the memory model of a JavaScript runtime is completely different to that of tex. I don't know how katex implements this argument, and JavaScript specific questions would be off topic here.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I checked the code of LaTex on GitHub. Using `-1` should work under the current implementation as you mentioned.